# Does finding a cycle with $\log n$ length in $\text{P}$?

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, graphs, lower-bounds

Let $G$ be an arbitrary graph with $n$ vertices and we want to find a simple cycle with $\log n$ length. Is there exists a known polynomial algorithm for this problem?

Comment: Do you mean [a closed walk or a simple cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_(graph_theory))?

Comment: @xskxzr A simple cycle.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [color-coding](http://courses.cs.tau.ac.il/combsem/09a/papers/ColorCoding.pdf), a celebrated technique due to Alon, Yuster and Zwick.