# Vertex Cover of size at most $\log n$

Tags: complexity-theory, vertex-cover

Consider the following language:
$$
L = \{ G | G \text{ has a VC of size at most } \log n \}
$$

Does $L\in P$ or $L\in NPC$?

Comment: What do you about algorithms for vertex cover?

Comment: @Juho I know $VC \in NPC$ obviously (verified easily). I also know that the language of graphs that has $VC$ of size at most $|V|/2$ is also in $NPC$ (proved using reduction from original $VC$ problem). But the same trick doesn't scale for $\log n$.

Comment: I think this problem is duplicate of https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/99710/does-finding-a-cycle-with-log-n-length-in-textp .

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_cover#Fixed-parameter_tractability has enough information to figure this out simply.

Comment: @LukeMathieson "Bounded Search Tree" does work, thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you solve [*Vertex Cover* with the simple branching algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_cover#Fixed-parameter_tractability), you achieve an [FPT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parameterized_complexity) running time of $2^k \text{poly}(n)$, where $k$ is an upper bound for the solution you are looking for.

Substituting $k$ for $\log n$ gives you the answer you are looking for.

Comment: Doesn't your answer assume that one cannot encode in $\text{poly}(k)$ a graph with $n=2^k$ vertices, while only the first $k$ vertices are not isolated? (See [my answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/110384/76159))

Comment: Thank you for helping me to realize the convention is to assume that the length of the encoding of a graph is in $\Omega(|V|)$. I deleted my answer. (If you think I should undelete it, please say so.)